# Fiddler Reuse client connections option makes C# application work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, fiddler

We have an MVC application which opens a url using window.open(url). It makes a GET request to that URL and the URL opens up in new window, which eventually loads up a form in it. When we exit the form, it creates PDF on server where we got the URL from.

When fiddler is turned on with Reuse Client connections options, everything works fine, but when I uncheck that option, the creating of the PDF doesn't work.

This issue only happens with the servers in a datacenter. It doesn't happen in our test system where servers are not in a datacenter. Are there any firewall setting that makes the connection close ? I googled it and found this link http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-02-28/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-

But I am not making HTTPWebRequest to explicitly set Keep Alive to true.

Is there any way I can programatically set Reuse client connection or Keep Alive to true when using window.open(url) ?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: A network capture would be useful to help troubleshoot this. My first guess is that your code that returns a PDF incorrectly uses `Response.Close` rather than `CompleteRequest`, as I wrote about here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/07/16/content-length-and-transfer-encoding-validation-in-ie10-download-manager-couldnt-be-downloaded-retry-cancel.aspx